# Sum of two numbers in arithmetic progression

Tags: number-theory

For any choice of 20 distinct numbers from the finite arithmetic progression 1, 4, 7, 10,...,100, I am trying to prove that there exist two distinct values among this choice of 20 whose sum is 104.  Letting ``1" be the zeroth term, I understand that the $n$th term is $3n+1$ and there are 34 total terms.  However, I am not sure where to go from here to show that irrespective of the choice of 20 numbers, there are two whose sum is always 104.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The terms are of the form $3k+1$.

So you have $(3k+1)+(3m+1)= 104$.

Is that possible?

Should be easy to see that that mean $3 (k+m)=102$ so $ (k+m )=34$.

Can you see that there are for k=1...16 and m =33...18 16 possible answers?

Comment: There aren't 17 possible answers, only 16 since you're taking into account 17+17=34, but the numbers picked have to be distinct.

Comment: Hmmm,  I guess so.

Answer (score 0):

Pair up the numbers that sum to 104:

```
1
4  <-> 100
7  <-> 97
10 <-> 94
...
49 <-> 55
52
```

This makes for 16 pairs and two unpaired numbers. Any selection from the arithmetic progression where no pair of numbers sums to 104 can only have at most one number from each pair and at most one of each of the unpaired numbers – such a set is therefore limited to 18 numbers. But we have chosen 20, so there must be at least two pairs of numbers in our selection that *do* sum to 104.